# Controller Mockmvc tests failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockmvc

I tried a bunch of annotations on the test class but all the time get this same error. I'm facing this error,

```
 Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.repository.ConfigRepo' in your configuration.

2021-07-01 16:26:14,387 ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager [main]: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@2101b44a] to prepare test instance [com.webapp.controller.ConfigControllerTest@1800c1e3]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

My controller code is something along this lines,

```
@WebMvcTest(ConfigController.class)
//@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ConfigControllerTest {

    public static final String BASE_PATH = CommonConstants.BASE_CONTEXT_PATH;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    @MockBean
    private AggregateService aggregateService;
  
    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }
```

and my Application.java is like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan({ "com.sample", "com.some-common-lib.sample" })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /**
     * The main method.
     *
     * @param args the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * Configure.
     *
     * @param builder the builder
     * @return the spring application builder
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Could someone help figure out why I can't run tests on controller classes?

Comment: Looks like you have a property or set of properties referred through spring config. This is not declared in the test. Are you missing a section of the code in the snippets?

Comment: The main class has a library in `ComponentScan` as posted which handles token auth. If needed can post Spring Security config. Also not sure why is it complaining about custom Repository file in tests while it doesn't in normal bootRun